# Actix Websocket seems to process requests serially

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have the StreamHandler that processes incoming requests from a server like the following snippet. The problem I'm having is that the `handle` function won't take a new element until the previous request is done. How can I execute requests concurrently? I tried to execute it in a separate thread like `thread:spawn` but the requests still got processed serially. The full code is here: https://github.com/hussachai/the-rusty-mole/blob/master/src/client/ws_client.rs#L161

```
impl StreamHandler<Result<Frame, WsProtocolError>> for WebSocketClient {

fn handle(&mut self, msg: Result<Frame, WsProtocolError>, ctx: &mut Context<Self>) {
    if let Ok(Frame::Binary(data)) = msg {
        ctx.address().do_send(client::BuildRequest { data: data.to_vec() });
    }
}

fn started(&mut self, _ctx: &mut Context<Self>) {
    info!("Connected");
}

fn finished(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context<Self>) {
    info!("Server disconnected");
    ctx.stop()
}
```

}

Comment: From Docs: Actix in general does support concurrency, but normal Arbiters (not SyncArbiters) do not. To use Actix in a concurrent way, you can spin up multiple Arbiters using Arbiter::new, ArbiterBuilder, or Arbiter::start.
https://actix.rs/book/actix/sec-5-arbiter.html#the-event-loop

Comment: See an example here: https://github.com/geofmureithi-zz/apalis/blob/a3a07fc452ccf23f531e679639a489047fe25a8e/packages/apalis-core/src/worker.rs#L45

Comment: Thanks for the help. The new example here https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/websockets/echo/src/client.rs 
doesn't have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not exactly how to fix it, there is a different approach that works with concurrency and it's simpler. The updated websocket example here doesn't have the issue. https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/websockets/echo/src/client.rs